# How to pass data from child action to layout in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, child-actions

I have a view which uses a layout, and also executes a child action.

The layout calls a partial which needs some data from the view's child action. Is there some way to pass the data up from the child action to it's parent view's layout?

I have tried solving this using sections, but it appears that sections can only be rendered in layout views.

Comment: what your child view is returning ? json or html ?

Comment: The child action is returning HTML.

Comment: there are many ways to do that..
1-you can call $.ajax call to child action and show where ever you want to show it.using jquery selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I had the child action stuff the required data into the HttpContext. This was then read out by the view containing the child action, which used it to render a section in the layout.

I was concerned that the order of processing of the views would not be predictable (i.e. that I couldn't be sure that the data would be written to the HttpContext before being read from it), but it turns out the order of processing is entirely predictable.

Answer (score 0):

In your child action, you can set up the data as `data-***` attributes and then use JavaScript (or jQuery) to read them back in your partial.

E.g. child action:

```
<div id="somedata" data-customerid="123" data-reference="xyz">
</div>
```

Then in your partial:

```
<script> 
   ....
   var customerId = $("#somedata").data("customerid");
   var reference = $("#somedata").data("reference");
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. This is an interesting suggestion but ideally I'm looking for a serverside solution.